# Can a location be determined from a 2nd VPN connection after going through a 1st VPN

Tags: vpn, citrix

I connect to the internet using Internet Explorer and VPN service to a company internet site. From the company internet site I open a Citrix remote desktop connection to a company computer. At this point can my location be determined by the company or do they still see only the endpoint from the original VPN?

If the final VPN is not providing the location, is it possible for Citrix to get that information from my pc if I'm using wifi at the time?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and move your comment into the question itself? You can edit your question [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/106834/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're looking at something along the lines of:

You <---> VPN1 <---> VPN2 <---> Citrix

Then the answer would, broadly speaking, be no. The company will see the external IP address of the first VPN as the origin for their VPN Tunnel.

Please note that this only applies to the VPN tunnel. If there's anything within the application which might be able to gather your location, then that will bypass any VPN system you have running.

Comment: Basically, if there's any application that's broadcasting your locations everywhere, like some protocols do (e.g. Torrent), then it doesn't really matter how many layers of VPN you're using.

Comment: Not just that. If it's a corporate remote access tool, then it might beacon out itself to ensure that you're not attempting to connect from somewhere that you shouldn't.